# How to know more about built-in modules

Tags: python, built-in

**OVERVIEW**

Once you've imported a package you can query the source path using the `__path__` attribute and from there most of the time you can read the Python source code directly. The problem comes when the module in question is similar to winreg. If I do

```
import winreg

print winreg.__path__
```

I'll get the path `['d:\\virtual_envs\\py2711\\lib\\site-packages\\winreg']`, and from there I can take a look to its source code, where I can see the `__init__.py` is doing:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from future.utils import PY3

if PY3:
    from winreg import *
else:
    __future_module__ = True
    from _winreg import *
```

Now, because I'm a very curious person I'd like to know more about the `_winreg` implementation so I try to do:

```
import _winreg

print winreg
print dir(_winreg)
```

And I get `_winreg` is `<module '_winreg' (built-in)>`.

Is there a *standard* way to know in which part of the source code is implemented some built-in package like this so I'll be able to read and debug it?

Comment: If all you have is the compiled binary, you'll have to look for the original source code elsewhere, wherever the particular library comes from…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python's modules written in C, you can always check CPython's source code over at GitHub: https://github.com/python/cpython

Usually you can find them in the `Modules` folder but the `winreg` one is special, here it is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/winreg.c

Comment: Though I'd note that's the Python 3 version of `winreg`. The Python 2 version, `_winreg`, is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/PC/_winreg.c).

Comment: @ChristopherC Is that the official CPython repo used for all python versions? For instance, I'd like to read the built-in modules source code of  `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` and `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: As written in the GitHup repo page, it is a read-only copy from the official one. I linked to it because I find it more friendly to navigate through GitHub than through the original Python repo page which is here: https://hg.python.org/. To find a specific commit version, such as v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, you can search for it (https://hg.python.org/cpython/log?rev=6d1b6a68f775), and browse the file you like (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6d1b6a68f775/PC/_winreg.c).